# How I can use cancel package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, fractions, mathtools, cancel

[image]

```
\dfrac{\cancel{4} \times \cancel{5} \times \cancel{3}}{\cancel{2} \times \cancel{10}}
```

Comment: @WhoSaveMeSaveEntireWorld Please write code in this picture's fraction.

Comment: This gentle member took time to give you a very understandable and adaptable answer and you think you cannot use it and adapt by yourself? I’m sure you can, and that’s a better way to learn than just begging for the exact solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!!

I'd do this with `tikz` and a `matrix of math nodes` from the (tikz) `matrix` library. The `calc` library could be useful too to control the positions (which can be improved as needed).

Something like the following:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round]
  \matrix(M)[blue,matrix of math nodes,
              row 3/.style={black},
              row 4/.style={black},
             ]
  {%
    1  &        &        &        &   \\
    2  &        & 1      &        &   \\
    4  & \times & 5      & \times & 3 \\
    {} & 2      & \times & 10     & {}\\
       & 1      &        &  2     &   \\
       &        &        &  1     &   \\
  };
  \draw (M-3-1.south west) -- (M-3-5.south east);
  \foreach\i/\j in {2/1,3/1,3/3,4/2,4/4,5/4}
    \draw[blue] ($(M-\i-\j.north west)-(0,0.1)$) -- ($(M-\i-\j.south east)+(0,0.1)$);
  \node at ($(M-3-5)!0.5!(M-4-5)+( 0.2,0.07)$) [right] {$\mathstrut=-3$};
  \node at ($(M-3-1)!0.5!(M-4-1)+(-0.2,0.07)$) [left]  {$\mathstrut-$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** Added minus signs, as the OP suggested.

Comment: Castano How to insert "-" symbol in front of fraction line?

Comment: @bayaraasurenjav, in the same way I put the `=3`. Create a new node at the appropriate position. For example: `\node at ($(M-3-1)!0.5!(M-4-1)+(-0.25,0.07)$) [left]  {$-$};`. You`ll need to add `{}` in the matrix below the 4, (as I did below the 3), if not there is no M-4-1 node for positioning.

Comment: Castano Sir. In the example above, before you write the fractional line - write the code so that it has a symbol.

Answer (score 1):

## First Example

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}% please change it to your own class, for example article, book, etc
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}
$
\begin{aligned}
t &=\frac{\bcancel{a}\times b}{\bcancel{a}} \\
  &= b
\end{aligned}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Second Example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}
Given $f(x)$. Find its derivative with respect to $x$.
\begin{align*}
    f'(x) &= \frac{\cancel{\mathrm{d}}f(x)}{\cancel{\mathrm{d}} x} \\
          &= \frac{f(x)}{x}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]